# how to generate random numbers of random colors for canvas.drawColor

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I am still new at android development and all the app i've been dealing with so far are not graphical related. Now i am making a app that displays a graph, pie graph to be exact and im making this without any 3rd party libs. [This](http://tutorials-android.blogspot.co.nz/2011/05/how-create-pie-chart-in-android.html) is the tutorial which i followed.

Now the problem is the data which i will be using to construct the graph is dynamic, and so to assign each item with a color for the graph i need to generate a number of random colors for the canvas.drawColor. the number of colors will of course depend on my dynamic data which is determined at run time and the color value also needs to be generated.
Also it would be nice if the colors generated are vibrant colors that stands out.

I've never dealt with canvas, any idea how this can be done? Example code would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: There is not really a question.  I'm sure there are lots of tutorials, with tons of example code, out there on using the android canvas you could look at. http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be quite hard to get different and usefull colors at runtime. The best is not to use so much randomness, but make an array of let's say 20 fixed colors quite distinct and use the X first ones for your data. If you need more, then maybe use real random colors using random RGB values :

```
Random r = new Random();
Color c = new Color( r.nextInt(255), r.nextInt(255), r.nextInt(255) );
```

Comment: Actually now u've mentioned it, would it be possible to create say 5 colors and loop through them with my data just making sure there is no same consecutive colors?

Comment: Random colors are easy to generate.  Making them look good is hard.  I agree that you'd be better off making an array of nice looking colors, 20-50 of them, then randomly choosing from those.

Comment: Shouldn't you use r.nextInt(256)? Since its the Upper limit?

Comment: @ariken929 yes that is the idea.

Comment: @user717572 you may be right, I would have considered this detail for my own code, but here I didn't check

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use just completely random colors. You'd get completely different saturations and brightnesses which will look plain ugly.

You could fix a saturation (choose a high value for vibrant colors) and brightness and choose a random hue value, but you would run the risk of getting two consecutive pie-slices with almost the same color.

I would compute a set of spread out hue-values as shown in the answer to this question:

- [How to dynamically compute a list of colors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403826/how-to-dynamically-compute-a-list-of-colors)

Reposting the answer below

---

```
import java.awt.*;

public class TestComponent extends JPanel {

    int numCols = 6;

    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        float h = 0, dh = (float) getHeight() / numCols;
        Color[] cols = getDifferentColors(numCols);

        for (int i = 0; i < numCols; i++) {
            g.setColor(cols[i]);
            g.fillRect(0, (int) h, getWidth(), (int) (h += dh));
        }
    }

    public static Color[] getDifferentColors(int n) {
        Color[] cols = new Color[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            cols[i] = Color.getHSBColor((float) i / n, 1, 1);
        return cols;
    }

    public static void main(String s[]) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new TestComponent());
        f.setSize(400, 400);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

[image]

If you need like more than 30 colors, you could of course change the brightness and perhaps the saturation as well, and have, for instance, 10 dark colors, 10 midtone colors, and 10 bright colors.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a random float for each color component:

```
Random rand = new Random();
float r = rand.nextFloat();
float g = rand.nextFloat();
float b = rand.nextFloat();
```

Since you want vibrant colors, you could use the `Color.brighter()` method.

```
Color c = new Color(r, g, b);
c = c.brighter();
```

Otherwise you could set a threshold, so that the color values have a minimum value (higher is brighter):

```
float minimumBrightness = 0.6; //higher is more vibrant
float r = rand.nextFloat(1-minimumBrightness) + minimumBrightness;  //for each  component
```

This will ensure vibrant colors.

Comment: ah ok, so this uses rgb values. the tutorial im following uses int colors[]={-6777216,-16776961,-16711681,-12303292,-7829368}; can you tell me what type of value this is?

Comment: It looks like rgb codes like `http://www.ceveni.com/2009/08/set-rgb-color-codes-for-android-and-rgb.html`, you can probably convert them with java. If I were you i'd use separate components tough. You could also define the colors in a range of 0-255 if you like.